# PostgreSQL different query plans on similar servers

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

On similar Amazon RDS PostgreSQL servers version 9.6.11 with the same databases I get different execution plans for one SQL query.

I tried to re-create indexes and run `ANALYZE` and `VACUUM`. Nothing helped me.

My query:

```sql
SELECT "users_employee"."id",
       (
           SELECT U0."created"
           FROM "surveys_surveyrequest" U0
           WHERE (U0."confirmed" IS NULL
                  AND U0."skipped" IS NULL
                  AND U0."from_member_id" = ("users_employee"."id"))
           ORDER BY U0."created" ASC
           LIMIT 1) AS "earliest_request_date"
FROM "users_employee"
ORDER BY "users_employee"."id" ASC;
```

Problem table information:

```
 create table surveys_surveyrequest
(
    id integer default nextval('public.surveys_surveyrequest_id_seq'::regclass) not null
        constraint surveys_surveyrequest_pkey
            primary key,
    created timestamp with time zone not null,
    skipped timestamp with time zone,
    from_member_id integer
        constraint surveys_surveyreques_from_member_id_81f0e82e_fk_users_emp
            references users_employee
                deferrable initially deferred,
    confirmed timestamp with time zone
);

create index surveys_sur_confirm_48bfa6_idx
    on surveys_surveyrequest (confirmed);

create index surveys_sur_created_099976_idx
    on surveys_surveyrequest (created);


create index surveys_surveyrequest_70b76ad7
    on surveys_surveyrequest (from_member_id);
```

Plans:
A:

```
                                                                                    QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using auth_user_pkey on users_employee  (cost=0.28..991903.69 rows=1478 width=12) (actual time=139.054..195486.465 rows=1478 loops=1)
   Heap Fetches: 51
   Buffers: shared hit=296637323
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..671.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=132.258..132.259 rows=1 loops=1478)
           Buffers: shared hit=296637288
           ->  Index Scan using surveys_sur_created_099976_idx on surveys_surveyrequest u0  (cost=0.42..24143.63 rows=36 width=8) (actual time=132.256..132.256 rows=1 loops=1478)
                 Filter: ((confirmed IS NULL) AND (skipped IS NULL) AND (from_member_id = users_employee.id))
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 405780
                 Buffers: shared hit=296637288
 Planning time: 0.188 ms
 Execution time: 195487.356 ms
(12 rows)
```

B:

```
                                                                                  QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using auth_user_pkey on users_employee  (cost=0.28..886476.74 rows=1578 width=12) (actual time=0.977..1043.414 rows=1578 loops=1)
   Heap Fetches: 0
   Buffers: shared hit=98270 read=8
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Limit  (cost=561.74..561.74 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.658..0.659 rows=1 loops=1578)
           Buffers: shared hit=98266 read=5
           ->  Sort  (cost=561.74..561.79 rows=22 width=8) (actual time=0.658..0.658 rows=1 loops=1578)
                 Sort Key: u0.created
                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                 Buffers: shared hit=98266 read=5
                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on surveys_surveyrequest u0  (cost=474.19..561.63 rows=22 width=8) (actual time=0.646..0.652 rows=13 loops=1578)
                       Recheck Cond: ((from_member_id = users_employee.id) AND (confirmed IS NULL))
                       Filter: (skipped IS NULL)
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                       Heap Blocks: exact=9707
                       Buffers: shared hit=98266 read=5
                       ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=474.19..474.19 rows=23 width=0) (actual time=0.641..0.641 rows=0 loops=1578)
                             Buffers: shared hit=88562 read=2
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on surveys_surveyrequest_70b76ad7  (cost=0.00..11.29 rows=382 width=0) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=258 loops=1578)
                                   Index Cond: (from_member_id = users_employee.id)
                                   Buffers: shared hit=5847 read=2
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on surveys_sur_confirm_48bfa6_idx  (cost=0.00..462.64 rows=24829 width=0) (actual time=0.826..0.826 rows=24756 loops=1165)
                                   Index Cond: (confirmed IS NULL)
                                   Buffers: shared hit=82715
 Planning time: 0.234 ms
 Execution time: 1043.680 ms
(26 rows)

Time: 1044,547 ms (00:01,045)
```

I expect the same query plans to be generated, but this does not happen.
What could be the reason?
How to achieve execution with the plan B?

Comment: Did you try to disable GEQO ? (SET geqo=false) Do you still have different QP after doing so ?

Comment: Nah. That only kicks in if there are more than `geqo_threshold` tables involved.

Comment: Don't know if it will make a difference for your problem, but it looks like `DISTINCT ON` would be simpler for your query. It should allow you to eliminate the subquery and just have a `JOIN`.

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks for that idea. As far as I know joins are faster and preferable  than subquery. Really good idea. I will test!

Comment: You might also want to consider a more specific index. As is, even your faster query plan has to bitmap-and two indexes, which can be a costly process, and then perform another filter after that. If you had a filtered index on the condition that those two columns are `NULL` (e.g., `CREATE INDEX ON surveys_surveyrequest (from_member_id, created) WHERE confirmed IS NULL AND skipped IS NULL`), the engine should be able to find the matching rows much more quickly. I'd experiment with including and omitting `created` from that index, too.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the configuration is the same on both servers and that all indexes are present and not marked “invalid”.

Assuming that to be the case, the difference might be that the data are distributed differently in both databases. Please `ANALYZE surveys_surveyrequest` and run the following on both databases:

```
SELECT correlation
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename = 'surveys_surveyrequest'
  AND attname = 'created';
```

My guess is that the value is close to 1 or -1 on A and close to 0 on B.

[That would explain](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/column-correlation-explained/) why PostgreSQL prefers an index scan on A. The problem with plan A is that PostgreSQL has to scan way more index rows than it bargained for, probably because the rows that match the condition are all far back in the index.

I'd say you should simply disable the index scan on `surveys_sur_created_099976_idx`,
either with

```
DROP INDEX surveys_sur_created_099976_idx;
```

or (if you need the index for other purposes) by using

```
ORDER BY U0."created" + INTERVAL '0 seconds'
```

Comment: correlation:
A=0.767555
B=0.755629

Comment: I do not understand the reason for different results, so I don’t want to get rid of the index or use doubtful ordering.

Comment: Configurations are equal.  Index is valid.

Comment: The ordering is not doubtful. Well, *something* is different between the installations. You just have to find it.

Comment: Try setting `enable_indexscan = off` and compare the estimated costs of the plans.